# AJAX call not working on jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In attempt to make my jQuery toggles more manageable; I'm trying to successfully pull it's content through an AJAX call, but my AJAX call kills my toggles -- any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong here?

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('#toggle3').click(function(){
            var $tog = $('.toggle');
            $tog.hide(1000);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'path/to/my/script.php',
                type: 'GET', //this is default anyway, only for verbosity
                success: function (fields){
                    $tog.html(fields);
                    $tog.slideToggle(1000);
                }
            });
        });
    });    
</script>
```

**Script.php** is a form essentially, nested in a div; just as below:

```
<div style="font-size: 12px; color: #000; text-align: left; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 20px;">
    <form>
        <br>Back wheel color?
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Purple"><span style="color: #B500E4">Purple</span>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="White">White</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Light Blue"><span style="color: #74A1C4;">Light Blue</span>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Blue">Blue</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Tan">Tan</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Grey">Grey</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Pink">Pink</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Red">Red</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Yellow">Yellow</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Black">Black</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Green"><span style="color:#44CA2C">Green</span>
        </br>
    </form>
    </span>
    </form>
    <br>Front Wheel (if different)
    <br>
    <form>
        <br>Front wheel color?
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Purple"><span style="color: #B500E4">Purple</span>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="White">White</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Light Blue"><span style="color: #74A1C4;">Light Blue</span>
        </br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Blue">Blue</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Tan">Tan</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Grey">Grey</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Pink">Pink</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Red">Red</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Yellow">Yellow</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Black">Black</br>
        <input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Green"><span style="color:#44CA2C">Green</span>
        </br>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="next"><a href="#" id="toggle3">Check Out!<img src="http://northbrooklyncollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/519629-129_ArrowRight-128.png" class="tool"></a>
</div>
```

Originally code that was working (below):

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle3').click(function () {
        $('.toggle').hide('1000');
        $('.toggle').html('<div style="font-size: 12px; color: #000; text-align: left; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 20px;"><form><br>Back wheel color?<br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Purple"><span style="color: #B500E4"><img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41S7CRzpV3L._AA160_.jpg" style="max-height: 100px;">Purple</span><br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="White">White</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Light Blue"><span style="color: #74A1C4;">Light Blue</span></br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Blue">Blue</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Tan">Tan</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Grey">Grey</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Pink">Pink</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Red">Red</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Yellow">Yellow</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Black">Black</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Green"><span style="color:#44CA2C">Green</span></br></form></span></form><br>Front Wheel (if different)<br><form><br>Front wheel color?<br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Purple"><span style="color: #B500E4">Purple</span><br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="White">White</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Light Blue"><span style="color: #74A1C4;">Light Blue</span></br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Blue">Blue</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Tan">Tan</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Grey">Grey</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Pink">Pink</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Red">Red</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Yellow">Yellow</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Black">Black</br><input type="radio" name="backwheel" value="Green"><span style="color:#44CA2C">Green</span></br></form></div><div id="next"><a href="#" id="toggle3">Check Out!<img src="http://northbrooklyncollective.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/519629-129_ArrowRight-128.png" class="tool"></a></div>');
        $('.toggle').slideToggle('1000');

        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: What does it do that isn't supposed to happen?

Comment: It dies, the toggle no longer works. Url has a # that appears - that's it, prior the toggle would appear with the form fields inclucded

Comment: Well, you're missing `});` at the end of the script. I'm not sure if that's just a post typo or that's your issue.

Comment: Thank you Josh, for you candor. Though it still dies with or without the extra }); I've updated my Q.

Comment: In your new code, try `var tog` instead of `var $tog` (and changing all the other $tog to just tog).   I believe using variable names starting with **$** is causing a conflict with your jQuery.   Variable names starting with $ is really a PHP standard (though valid in JS), but not necessary here.

Comment: You forgot to change $tog on this line `var $tog = $('.toggle');`.  The page is giving a JS error now because the variable isn't defined.

Comment: Holy CRAP! It worked; Charlie please add as an answer with the removale of $. Thanks a lot man, saved me a ton!

Comment: You are very welcome...  will post as an answer now. Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case is that your variable name ($tog) starts with a dollar sign.   While this is technically a valid Javascript variable name, it is conflicting with the jQuery library which also starts with $.

While PHP uses $ for variable names, this is not standard in Javascript.

You can update the code as follows to resolve:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#toggle3').click(function(){
    var tog = $('.toggle');
    tog.hide(1000);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/my/script.php',
        type: 'GET', //this is default anyway, only for verbosity
        success: function (fields){
            tog.html(fields);
            tog.slideToggle(1000);
        }
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: No, that's not the case. JavaScript has no problem with a variable called `$` and another variable called `$tog` just as it would have no problem with having one called `a` and one called `atog`.

Comment: @Quentin, I believe you read this incorrectly.   The variable was called `$tog`.   This was conflicting with jQuery and was not working.   Renaming the variable to just `tog` resolved the issue for the OP.   The site has already been fixed based on this solution.   Please remove your downvote.

Comment: While the problem might have been resolved, it wasn't because a variable was renamed "so it wouldn't conflict with jQuery". As I said, `$` and `$tog` can happily co-exist in JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin there was no variable named `$`.   Only `$tog`.   Renaming `$tog` to `tog` resolved the issue.   Please take time to read the question / answer / comments before downvoting.

Comment: Loading the jQuery library creates a variable called `$` (and stores a function in it). You said this conflicted with having a variable called `$tog` which is nonsense.

Comment: I agree with Quentin - $ and $tog can be defined in the same scope without any problem (it is disputable practice though). I don't believe that this was actually causing the problem. In your example HTML I don't see any element with toggle class. I don't know if that is just post typo, but that would surely make your code not working.